# django - MySQL strict mode with database url in settings

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-settings

I'm using a database URL string in my settings like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': "mysql://root:@localhost:3306/mydb"
}
```

When I migrate I get this warning:

```
MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
```

Now my question: How can I combine the two things?

**I cannot use the "regular" way to set the database settings with a dictionary because my database url comes from an environment variable.**

Thx in advance!

Comment: did you try [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) can it help you?

Comment: @BearBrown might work but isn't there a way without using another plugin?

Comment: i think no, only if you add snippet, but it will be the like code of the plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could update your settings afterwards:

```
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this one will help you.
you can pass the **options** as a query string in the URL

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default="mssql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NAME?init_command=SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'&charset=utf8mb4", conn_max_age=500)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test123',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        }
    }
}
```

Try to give init_command of database options in settings.py
If want know more refer the docs [django_mysql.W001: Strict Mode](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks.html)

Comment: thx for the input but as I stated in my question I cannot use a dictionary, I have to stick to the url string. Any ideas about that?

Comment: sorry, i dont get what you mean.

Comment: see @vijay answer